# Fabric.js toJSON() method missing image

Tags: javascript, serialization, fabricjs

I am having difficulty returning all canvas objects in the .toJSON() method.

in my test http://jsfiddle.net/EqeZj/ (Fabric.js v1.4.8) it seems to only be returning the shape object.

```
// Do some initializing stuff
    fabric.Object.prototype.set({
        transparentCorners: false,
        cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
        cornerSize: 12,
        padding: 5
    });

    // initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
    var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 250,
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        fill: '#0B61A4'
    }));

    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png', function(img) {
      img.left = 58;
      img.top = 110;
      canvas.add(img);
    });

    canvas.includeDefaultValues = false;
    fabric.log('JSON without default values: ', canvas.toJSON());
    fabric.log('canvas.getObjects ', canvas.getObjects());
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with async image loading: if you wait some seconds the image will be present in JSON object as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7BR8E/1/

So if you want to be sure to manipulate a canvas with the image loaded you must do it inside callback function of `fromURL()` after `canvas.add(img)`.